How can I configure asp net core authorization to find the user's roles from my custom DB schema?
I've got SQL Server tables Users, Roles and SecurityGroups, each containing an integer ID and a NVARCHAR Name. I also have mapping tables User_SecurityGroup and SecurityGroup_Role. A user can be in multiple security groups and a security group can be mapped to multiple roles.
I already have a function to get a user's role list.
    public async Task<List<string>> GetUserRoles(string userId)
    {
        List<string> userRoles = new List<string>();

        try
        {
            var securityGroupIds = db.User.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == userId).SecurityGroupIdList.ToList();
            userRoles = db.SecurityGroupRole.Where(sgr => securityGroupIds.Contains(sgr.SecurityGroupId)).Select(sgr => sgr.RoleId).ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        return userRoles;
    }

User.Identity.Name is populated correctly (I'm using windows authentication for now). What I can't figure out is how to configure asp net core so that when I put an Authorize attribute like this:
[Authorize(Roles = "SystemAdmin")]
on a page, it runs my function to get the user's role list and checks that, in this example, SystemAdmin is among them. I'm not sure how to wire things up.

Check this, it might be help you.

To achieve your requirement, you can custom AuthorizationHandler to handle role-based authorization using your GetUserRoles function.
Define a Custom Authorization Requirement:
public class SystemAdminRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement { }

Create a Custom Authorization Handler:
public class SystemAdminAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<SystemAdminRequirement>
{
     private readonly ApplicationDbContext db;
     public SystemAdminAuthorizationHandler(ApplicationDbContext db)
     {
         this.db = db;
     }

    protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, SystemAdminRequirement requirement)
    {
        if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            context.Fail(); // User is not authenticated
            return;
        }

        var userId = context.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;
        var userRoles = await GetUserRoles(userId);

        if (userRoles.Contains("SystemAdmin"))
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement); // User is authorized
        }
        else
        {
            context.Fail(); // User does not meet the requirement
        }
    }

    public async Task<List<string>> GetUserRoles(string userId)
    {
        List<string> userRoles = new List<string>();

        try
        {
            var securityGroupIds = db.User.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == userId).SecurityGroupIdList.ToList();
            userRoles = db.SecurityGroupRole.Where(sgr => securityGroupIds.Contains(sgr.SecurityGroupId)).Select(sgr => sgr.RoleId).ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        return userRoles;
    }
}

Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser,IdentityRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

 //Register your custom authorization handler
builder.Services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, SystemAdminAuthorizationHandler>();
//Define a policy ...
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("SystemAdminPolicy", policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
        policy.Requirements.Add(new SystemAdminRequirement());
    });
});

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();

